# Es gibt hier jede Menge hohe Berge drum herum

Tags: sentence-structure

In what case is Berge here? Nominative or genitive?
I understood that "Menge" might express discrete values (uncountable large numbers) and in this case it comes with "unbestimmten Artikel: e.g eine / jede. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

*Berge* is neither nominative nor genitive in your example:

It is in fact accusative. The non-personal use of "geben" (for "sth exists") generally rules the accusative.

Note you *could* properly express the same fact with a *genitivus partitivus* such as

> Es gibt hier jede Menge hohe**r** Berge

"jede Menge" literally means "any amount of", so "a lot". Very much so as in English.

Comment: "Wen/Was gibt es hier jede Menge drum herum ? - Berge" Correct ?

Comment: @Doomenik Yes, correct. But the standard way of "asking" for a subject/object to find the proper case tends to help learners much less than native speakers sometimes think.

Comment: Yes ty your probably right.

Answer (score 1):

It is accusative case.

- Nom: hohe Berge

  > **Hohe Berge** sind schön.
- Gen: hohe**r** Berge

  > Beim Anblick **hoher Berge** möchte Lisa jodeln.
- Dat: hohe**n** Berge**n**

  > Bei den **hohen Bergen** scheint die Sonne.
- Acc: hohe Berge

  > Ich sehe **hohe Berge**.

So, »hohe Berge« can only be nominative or accusative case. Genitive is out of the game.

It is possible, but rare, that something other than the subject appears in nominative case in a German sentence. The subject in this sentence is the first word »es«, which is an [expletive subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive). So it is very unlikely, that something else than the high mountains are in nominative case. But this is just a rule of thumb.

What really helps is the phrase »es gibt« itself (*there is* or *there are* in English). The thing(s) that is/are, always appears in accusative case. This means, that the nominal group *»jede Menge hohe Berge«* has to stand in accusative case.

But you asked for *»hohe Berge«*, so we have to split up the four-word phrase into its components:

There are two ways to express *every amount of high mountains* in German:

1. > Es gibt jede Menge hohe**r** Berge

   As shown above, *hoher Berge* is genitive case, and this variation is called »genitivus partitivus«. It expresses, that the amount (which stands in accusative case) consists of high mountains. (Note, that here *hoher Berge* is an ad-on to *jede Menge*. So the rule »*es gibt* needs accusative case applies to *jede Menge*.)
2. > Es gibt jede Menge hohe Berge

   This is the same construction as in *»es gibt zwei hohe Berge«* (*there are two high mountains*) or *»es gibt viele hohe Berge«* (*there are many high mountains*). This means: Here the words *jede Menge* (which in this construction are a quantifier, not an object) are an ad-on to *hohe Berge*, and the sentence works without this ad-on too:

   > Es gibt hohe Berge

   Now it is clear: Since »es gibt« always needs in object in accusative case, *hohe Berge* must stand in this case. And adding a quantifier doesn't change this case.

Comment: Wenn ich versuche "Ich sehen hohe Berge." in die richtige Form "Ich sehe..."  zu bringen, beklagt sich stackexchange dass zu wenig geändert wurde. Magst du sehen ins Singular bringen?